# How to open Mono app with GUI in Linux server without X?

Tags: ssh, xorg, display, xserver, mono

Im running a Mono application whose source code I cannot edit.

> $ mono app.exe
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Could not open display **(X-Server required. Check you DISPLAY environment variable)**
>
> Parameter name: Display

This server is only access through `ssh` and has no graphical interface. I've installed `xserver-xorg` and set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0`, but the error is still there. Also, running `xhost` complains that the display cannot be opened.

So, **how can I open my Mono app?** I don't mind discarding the GUI entirely, I just need the app to run.

---

Following one of the answers, I've unset the `DISPLAY` variable, connected through `ssh` with the `-X` option and tried `xhost +`, but I get an `unable to open display ""` error.

Turns out when I `ssh`, I get a `X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0` error upon connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undo your superstitious setting of `$DISPLAY`. It's trying to access the (nonexistent) X Server on "This server is only access through ssh and has no graphical interface". Uninstalling `xserver-xorg` is optional, but you must fix `$DISPLAY`.

On your originating system, initiate the connection using the `-X` or `-Y` option (see `man ssh`). You may have to `xhost +` the server.

And you need an X server on the client. – @bodhi.zazen

Comment: And you need an X server on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-fix-x11-forwarding-request-failed-on-channel-0/) to edit the `sshd` configs and setting.

> X11Forwarding yes
>
> X11UseLocalhost no

My `ssh` connection could then properly forward X apps and I could start my mono app.